# Sorting an array by increasing numerical order

Tags: vba

For some reason, the following function sorts the array not numerically, but by string value. An array of

```
1
7
9
15
18
6
14
17
16
```

gets sorted into

```
1
14
15
16
17
18
19
6
7
9
```

Here's the code:

```
    For i = LBound(months_array) To UBound(months_array) - 1
        For j = i + 1 To UBound(months_array)
            If UCase(months_array(i)) > UCase(months_array(j)) Then
                Temp = months_array(j)
                months_array(j) = months_array(i)
                months_array(i) = Temp
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
```

I've checked the data type of the element, and they seem to be numerical - Ican't fully verify though

Comment: UCase() returns a string - why are you using that if your elements are numeric?

Comment: Ah I didn't know that... What should I use for integers instead, UBound()?

Comment: Nvm I'm stupid, I shouldn't use any function here...

Comment: If you really wanted to use something then CInt() or CLng() would be what you'd use.

Answer (score 1):

If your array elements are numeric then why use UCase() ?

You should not need anything beyond a direct comparison:

```
For i = LBound(months_array) To UBound(months_array) - 1
    For j = i + 1 To UBound(months_array)
        If months_array(i) > months_array(j) Then
            Temp = months_array(j)
            months_array(j) = months_array(i)
            months_array(i) = Temp
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```